# JAX_WS: How to get an attachment on server present in SOAP Message context?

Tags: soap, jax-ws

I have used below function but getting error: "loading constraint violation: loader "com/ibm/ws/classloader/CompoundClassLoader@72127212" previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/w3c/dom/DOMConfiguration" defined by loader "com/ibm/oti/vm/BootstrapClassLoader@3d303d30""

```
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;
import org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.MessageContext;  
    private void downloadAttachment() throws AddDocumentException,SOAPException
        {

            org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext messagecontext = org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext.getCurrentMessageContext();
            log.info("1");
            MessageContext mc=new MessageContext(messagecontext);
            log.info("2");
            SOAPMessage soapmessage = mc.getMessage().getAsSOAPMessage();
            log.info("3");
            log.info("SOAP header: "+soapmessage.getSOAPHeader());
            log.info("4");
            log.info("SOAP Body: "+soapmessage.getSOAPBody());
            log.info("5");
            log.info("SOAP Part:"+soapmessage.getSOAPPart());
            log.info("6");
            File fDumpFolder=new File(sDumpLoc);
            if(!fDumpFolder.exists())
                fDumpFolder.mkdir();
            log.info("Count of attachments: "+soapmessage.countAttachments());
            if(soapmessage.countAttachments()==0)
                throw new AddDocumentException("-11011",pCodes.getString("-11011"),"");
            else if(soapmessage.countAttachments()>1)
                throw new AddDocumentException("-11012",pCodes.getString("-11012"),"");
            else if(soapmessage.countAttachments()==1)
            {
                 Iterator it = soapmessage.getAttachments();
                 AttachmentPart attachment=(AttachmentPart) it.next();
                 String sContentType=attachment.getContentType();
                 log.debug(attachment.getContentId()+", "+attachment.getContentType()+", "+attachment.getContentId());

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working now by removing xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar from axis2